# How to use OnClick Listener for a Thread Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, onclicklistener

I want to run a ONCLICKLISTENER in my app to execute the following thread like a start and stop

```
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder.AudioSource;
import android.media.AudioFormat;


class recorderThread extends Thread {
public boolean recording;  //variable to start or stop recording
public int frequency; //the public variable that contains the frequency value "heard", it is updated continually while the thread is running.
public recorderThread () {
}

@Override
        public void run() {
                AudioRecord recorder;
                int numCrossing,p;
                short audioData[];
                int bufferSize;

                bufferSize=AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCDING_PCM_16BIT)*3; //get the buffer size to use with this audio record

recorder = new AudioRecord (AudioSource.MIC,8000,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,bufferSize); //instantiate the AudioRecorder

recording=true; //variable to use start or stop recording
audioData = new short [bufferSize]; //short array that pcm data is put into.


while (recording) {  //loop while recording is needed
        if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.STATE_INITIALIZED) // check to see if the recorder has initialized yet.
        if (recorder.getRecordingState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_STOPPED)
              recorder.startRecording();  //check to see if the Recorder has stopped or is not recording, and make it record.

        else {

        recorder.read(audioData,0,bufferSize); //read the PCM audio data into the audioData array

        //Now we need to decode the PCM data using the Zero Crossings Method

        numCrossing=0; //initialize your number of zero crossings to 0
        for (p=0;p<bufferSize/4;p+=4) {
               if (audioData[p]>0 && audioData[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p]<0 && audioData[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p+1]>0 && audioData[p+2]<=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p+1]<0 && audioData[p+2]>=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p+2]>0 && audioData[p+3]<=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p+2]<0 && audioData[p+3]>=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p+3]>0 && audioData[p+4]<=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p+3]<0 && audioData[p+4]>=0) numCrossing++;
                }//for p

          for (p=(bufferSize/4)*4;p<bufferSize-1;p++) {
                if (audioData[p]>0 && audioData[p+1]<=0) numCrossing++;
                if (audioData[p]<0 && audioData[p+1]>=0) numCrossing++;
                }



frequency=(8000/bufferSize)*(numCrossing/2);  // Set the audio Frequency to half the number of zero crossings, times the number of samples our buffersize is per second.

                 }//else recorder started

        } //while recording

        if (recorder.getState()==android.media.AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING) recorder.stop(); //stop the recorder before ending the thread
        recorder.release(); //release the recorders resources
        recorder=null; //set the recorder to be garbage collected.

        }//run


}//recorderThread
```

I have a button and textView in my layout 
I want to display the frequency value of the recording going on continously when press the button Start and it should stop when I press the button again

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? There seem to be two separate issues here -- (1) how to use an `onClickListener` to start and stop a thread, and (2) how to update the UI from the `recorderThread`.

Comment: [1]how to use an onClickListener to start and stop a thread @acj